# What's a secure way to redirect to login.aspx?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Right now I'm writing an ASP.NET web application from scratch, and I want all users that aren't logged in to be redirected to `Login.aspx`. Here's the code from my master page:

```
protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnInit(e);
    if (this.Session["User"] == null && !this.Request.Path.EndsWith("Login.aspx")) {
        Response.Redirect("Login.aspx", true);
    }
}
```

However, I'm concerned that a potentially malicious user could browse the site (albeit with no data) by entering something like `https://mywebsite.com/Default.aspx?id=Login.aspx`. In the debugger it doesn't appear to contain the extra parameters but I'm wondering if there are any ways the user could manipulate this to view other pages. My question is, is it secure to use `Request.Path` like this?

Comment: Why don't you use `web.config` ?

Comment: Have you looked into forms authentication? http://support.microsoft.com/kb/301240/en-us

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to reinvent the wheel, ASP.NET has such features built-in:

Look into [form authentications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xdt4thhy%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

```
<system.web>
  <authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms loginUrl="Login.aspx" name=".ASPXFORMSAUTH">
    </forms>
  </authentication>
</system.web>
```

Answer (score 1):

After making changes to web.config as suggested by @meda
Try this.

```
if (!User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
       Response.Redirect("Login.aspx", true);
    }
```